# Creating a Web Page background fade with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website that when you open it, the background fades into a different color.

**Example:**

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes {
    from {
        background: white;
    }

    to {
        background: #F7F2E0;
    }
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes {
    from {
        background: white;
    }

    to {
        background: #F7F2E0;
    }
}

@keyframes {
    from {
        background: white;
    }

    to {
        background: #F7F2E0;
    }
}
```

But when I run the script, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a name to the animation and then add the animation properties to the desired element(s).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/68Xgx/)

```
@keyframes background {
    from {
        background:white;
    }
    to {
        background:#000;
    }
}
```

In the [animation shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) below, the value `forwards` is added for the `animation-fill-mode` property in order to end the animation at the last color.

```
body {
    animation: background 4s forwards;
}
```

*Vendor prefixes omitted for simplicity - see [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/68Xgx/) for the full CSS.*

I'd suggest reading more about [CSS animations at **MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name to your keyframe and and then apply it to the body. [See this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes). For animations and browser support [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

```
@keyframes fadeBackgroud{
    from {
        background:white;
    } to {
        background:#F7F2E0;
    }
}

body {
    animation:fadeBackgroud 5s infinite;
}
```